# I am getting "Scalar subquery contains more than one row" for following query I wrote.Can someone please correct me?

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables are

1. customer (id, name, country)

[image: customer table]

2. purchase (id, customer_id, year)

[image: PURCHASE Table]

I would like to see following 3 things

each customer's id (rename the column cus_id),
each customer's name (rename the column cus_name)
purchase id of their latest purchase (rename the column latest_purchase_id)

Please note that purchase ids are mix of integer and character so to find latest id, i need to find latest year.Multiple purchase are possible in a year

My code :

```
select customer.id as cus_id,customer.name as cus_name,purchase.id as latest_purchase_id
from customer
 join purchase
 on customer.id=purchase.customer_id
 where purchase.id=(select id
from purchase p1
where year = ( select max(year)
              from purchase p2
              where p1.customer_id=p2.customer_id))
         ;
```

sample output

```
cus_id cus_name latest_purchase_id
1      John        786F
```

I am receiving scalar subquery receives more than one row error.

Comment: Provide example data and what your results are requested to be.  The error is telling you the issue, one of your subquery is returning more than one row.  You can change it to an IN statement instead of = if that is your desired results

Comment: sure let me add example data

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
select c.id as cus_id, c.name as cus_name, p.id as latest_purchase_id
from customer c join
     purchase p
     on c.id = p.customer_id
where p.id = (select p2.id
-----------^
              from purchase p2
              where p2.year = (select max(p3.year)
                               from purchase p3
                               where p2.customer_id = p3.customer_id
                              )
            );
```

To fix this problem, change the `=` to `in`.  However, without a description of what you are doing, I can't tell if this does anything useful.

If you want the latest purchase for each customer, I am thinking of something like this:

```
select c.id as cus_id, c.name as cus_name, p.id as latest_purchase_id
from customer c join
     purchase p
     on c.id = p.customer_id join
     (select p2.customer_id, max(p2.year) as max_year
      from purchase p2
      group by p2.customer_id
     ) p2
     on p2.customer_id = p.customer_id and
        p2.max_year = p.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select customer.id as cus_id,customer.name as cus_name,purchase.id as 
latest_purchase_id
from customer join purchase p1 on customer.id=p1.customer_id
where year = 
( select max(year) from purchase p2
              where p1.customer_id=p2.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

> scalar subquery receives more than one row

It means the `(select id from purchase p1 ...)` is returning more than one row. And well... you can't use a plain equal (`=`) against multiple rows.

You have two options:

1. You need to make sure it returns a single row, maybe using a `MAX()` function (or other), as in:

   ```
   where purchase.id = (select MAX(id)
     from purchase p1 ...
   ```
2. Use an aggregator operator (like `ANY`). For example:

   ```
   where purchase.id = ANY (select id
     from purchase p1 ...
   ```